# Oracle SQL: WHERE NOT EXITSTS not functioning properly

Tags: subquery, oracle-sqldeveloper, not-exists

1st table

```
CREATE TABLE qualified (
    facultyid integer NOT NULL,
    courseid character varying(16) NOT NULL,
    datequalified character varying(16),
    dq2 date,
    CONSTRAINT qualified_pkey PRIMARY KEY (facultyid, courseid)
);

INSERT INTO qualified VALUES (3467, 'ISM 4212', to_date('9/1995', 'MM/YYYY'), date '1995-09-01');
INSERT INTO qualified VALUES (4756, 'ISM 3112', to_date('9/1991', 'MM/YYYY'), date '1991-09-01');
INSERT INTO qualified VALUES (2143, 'ISM 3113', to_date('9/1988', 'MM/YYYY'), date '1988-09-01');
INSERT INTO qualified VALUES (4756, 'ISM 3113', to_date('9/1991', 'MM/YYYY'), date '1991-09-01');
INSERT INTO qualified VALUES (2143, 'ISM 3112', to_date('9/1988', 'MM/YYYY'), date '1988-09-01');
INSERT INTO qualified VALUES (3467, 'ISM 4930', to_date('9/1996', 'MM/YYYY'), date '1996-09-01');
```

2nd table:

```
CREATE TABLE faculty (
    facultyid integer NOT NULL,
    facultyname character varying(25),
    CONSTRAINT faculty_pkey PRIMARY KEY (facultyid)
);

INSERT INTO faculty VALUES (2143, 'Birkin');
INSERT INTO faculty VALUES (3467, 'Berndt');
INSERT INTO faculty VALUES (4756, 'Collins');
```

The following query with the minus operator displayed the correct result:

```
SELECT q.facultyid, facultyname
FROM qualified q, faculty fa
WHERE q.facultyid = fa.facultyid AND courseid = 'ISM 3113'
MINUS
SELECT q.facultyid, facultyname
FROM qualified q, faculty fa
WHERE q.facultyid = fa.facultyid AND courseid = 'ISM 4930';
```

The following WHERE NOT EXISTS displays the incorrect result

```
SELECT q.facultyid, facultyname
FROM qualified q, faculty fa
WHERE q.facultyid = fa.facultyid AND courseid = 'ISM 3113'
AND NOT EXISTS  (SELECT q.facultyid, facultyname
                   FROM qualified q, faculty fa
                   WHERE q.facultyid = fa.facultyid AND courseid = 'ISM 4930');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked.
The 2nd WHERE clause must feature an ALIAS referring to the table listed in the first FROM clause that possess all the columns to be listed in the first SELECT clause.

```
SELECT q.facultyid, facultyname
FROM qualified q, faculty fa
WHERE q.facultyid = fa.facultyid AND courseid = 'ISM 3113'
AND NOT EXISTS  (SELECT q.facultyid, facultyname
                   FROM qualified q2, faculty fa2
                   WHERE q2.facultyid = fa.facultyid AND courseid = 'ISM 4930');
```

Better query:

```
SELECT fa.facultyid, facultyname
FROM qualified q, faculty fa
WHERE q.facultyid = fa.facultyid AND courseid = 'ISM 3113'
AND NOT EXISTS  (SELECT facultyid
                   FROM qualified
                   WHERE facultyid = fa.facultyid AND courseid = 'ISM 4930');
```

Thanks to 'Joel Murach MySQL' text book for having a similar question.